# Can java program which is on the client run the python script on the server?

Tags: java, python

Now I have a python script on the server.And running this script will generate a file. However, because the client can not run the python script, I want to develop a java program on the client to run the python on the server and then return the file.How can I implement this java program?

Comment: Have you considered using a cron job to automate this task? Why can't the client directly execute the python script?

Comment: Is the script in some way listening for requests from clients?  If not, something is going to need to do that.  You'd need some service running on the server which accepts requests from clients and invokes whatever server-side functionality it needs to.  Once you have that, it doesn't matter what language any given client is written in.  As long as it can send requests to the server.

Comment: Oups, Java is only a programming language. Before trying to implement it in Java you must crealy describe what tasks should be done and which underlying protocols can be used. If in doubt, feel free to ask here how a specific protocol can be implemented in Java given your specific context. But currently this question is really *too broad*.